# Правильное использование функции Concat

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как добавить к числу %, есть запрос к примеру:

```
Select 
Concat(a.Retention,'%')
From 
Applications a
```

тип `a.Retention - float`
получаю ошибку :

```
**Error converting data type varchar to float.**
```

Т.е ожидаю такой результат:

```
20%
15%
```

вместо 20, 15

Comment: А как можно к числу добавлять '%'. в математике нет такой операции, вам видимо надо предварительно превратить число в строку (см. cast, convert)

Comment: @Mike, попробывал так Concat(cast(a.Retention as nvarchar(50)),'%') та же ошибка

Comment: Значит ошибка у вас где то еще. Вы показали весь запрос ? просто очень странно, что оно пытается привести наоборот varchar к float'у

Comment: И да, я попробовал `select concat(cast(1.33 as float),'%')` оно ошибки не вызывает...

Comment: @Mike, да вы правы в колонке Retention были записи с null, исправил  Concat(cast(Isnull(Retention,'') as float),'%')

Answer (score 0):

У меня так работает

```
Select Concat(cast(Isnull(Retention,'') as float),'%') Out
From (
    Select null as Retention 
    Union All
    Select 1000 as Retention
) q

Out
-----
0%
1000%
```